# How can I use the output of Tarraform Coud workspace as provider configuration?

Tags: terraform

I have a workspace that creates an AKS cluster, which is destroyed and recreated each day. I have another workspace that deploys an application stack into the cluster. Each day I have to copy the generated host & credentials into the application stack workspaces, which is tedious and error prone.

So the idea is to take the output of the AKS workspace and use them in the kubernetes stack, based on this https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html

However, the settings are not loaded and my theory is data sources cannot be used in provider modules only resources?

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "aks" {
  backend = "remote"
  config = {
    organization = "xxxx"
    workspaces = {
      name = "aks_prod"
    }
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.host

  client_certificate = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.client_certificate)
  client_key = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.client_certificate)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.aks.outputs.client_certificate)
}
```

If this is true, then I will probably have to use the REST API to push the outputs to my workspaces, but obviously I would prefer to use a native Terraform solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It does work perfectly with Provider! I was replacing input variables with data, but forgot to actually delete the variable definitions, doh!